# Distance formula for MariaDB nearest 200 places without radius

Tags: php, geometry, mariadb

I have MariaDB, Server version: 10.0.23-MariaDB, with latitude and longitude columns (float 10,6) plus a geo_location column (geometry) that was calculated from the latitude and longitude columns.

I would like to find the nearest 200 people from a person. The person at the center has a latitude and longitude that is passed to the query. Is there a way to do that without a radius? So, if the population density is high the radius would be small. If the population density is low then the radius would be large.

There are about 4 million rows, and it needs to be as fast as possible. The rows can be filtered first based on the county that they reside. Some counties are super large with low population density and others are small counties with high population density. I need the fastest way to find the nearest 200 people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, ST_DISTANCE(geo_location, POINT(lon, lat)) AS distance 
FROM geotable 
ORDER by distance DESC
LIMIT 200;
```

The bad news is that it will be very slow, because no spatial indexes are used by st_distance(). You should try to restrict your query by using a maximum radius to select less records:

```
set @dist = 100;
set @rlon1 = lon-@dist/abs(cos(radians(lat))*69);
set @rlon2 = lon+@dist/abs(cos(radians(lat))*69);
set @rlat1 = lat-(@dist/69);
set @rlat2 = lat+(@dist/69); 

SELECT *, ST_DISTANCE(geo_location, POINT(lon, lat)) AS distance 
FROM geotable 
WHERE ST_WITHIN(geo_location,ENVELOPE(LINESTRING(point(@rlon1, @rlat1), point(@rlon2, @rlat2)))) 
ORDER by distance DESC 
LIMIT 200;
```

Or if you have the POLYGON coordinates of each country, you could use that instead of a maximum radius.

Comment: Sorry, there is a spatial index on geo_location column. Trying to avoid haversine too. It seems to be super slow.

Comment: I meant: ST_DISTANCE() do not use spatial index even if it's defined in InnodB. You have to be in MYISAM to use spatial indexes.

Answer (score 0):

6 decimal places is good enough (16cm / 0.5 ft), but `FLOAT` (1.7m / 5.6 ft) looses some of that precision.  It is essentially never good to tack `(M,N)` onto `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`; you incur 2 roundings, one of which is a waste.

The is no straightforward way to "find nearest" on the globe because there are no "2-dimensional" indexes.  However, by using partitioning for one dimension and a clustered `PRIMARY KEY` for the other, you can do a pretty good job.

The real problem with most solutions is the large number of disk blocks that need to be hit without finding valid items.  In fact, usually well over 90% of the rows touched are not needed.

All of this is 'solved' in [My lat/lng blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).  It will touch maybe 800 rows to get the 200 you desire, and they will be well clustered, so only a few blocks need be touched.  It does not need any pre-filtering on Country, but it does need some radical restructuring of the table.  And, if you want to distinguish two people embracing each other, I suggest a scaled `INT` (16mm / 5/8 in) - Degrees * 10000000.  Also, `FLOAT` won't work with `PARTITIONing`; `INT` will.  The code in that link uses a `MEDIUMINT` scaled (2.7m / 8/8 ft), but that could be changed.